# Summing grouped datetime data in python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, group-by

My data consists of packages and driving times:

```
      Package number  Route  ... Driving Time Working Time
0                   1    203  ...      0:15:00      0:15:00
1                   1    203  ...      0:25:00      0:25:00
2                   1    203  ...      0:00:00      0:10:00
3                   1    203  ...      0:10:00      0:10:00
4                   1    203  ...      0:20:00      0:20:00
              ...    ...  ...          ...          ...
58970            2679     30  ...      0:03:00      0:03:00
58971            2679     30  ...      0:17:00      0:17:00
58972            2680     30  ...      0:03:00      0:03:00
58973            2680     30  ...      0:17:00      0:17:00
58974            2681     30  ...      0:17:00      0:17:00
```

I have grouped the data using:

```
gby=df1.groupby('Package number')
print(gby)
```

but is there a way of finding the sum/total driving time for each package?
I currently get the error...

```
TypeError: DatetimeIndex cannot perform the operation sum
```

when I use

```
dt=gby['Driving Time'].sum()
```

And 'Driving Time' has been formatted into datetime

Many thanks :)

Comment: What code raise error?

Comment: @jezrael dt=gby['Driving Time'].sum()

Comment: A [minimal reproducible example is always recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example#:~:text=Minimal%20and%20readable,correctly%20formatted%20on%20Stack%20Overflow) since it avoids the confusion that we see from the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you cannot sum up datetime, you'll want to cast the respective column(s) [to_timedelta](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html), ex:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Driving Time': ["0:15:00", "0:25:00", "0:30:00", "0:30:00"], 
                   'Package number': [1,2,3,3]})

df['Driving Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Driving Time'])

grouped = df.groupby('Package number')
dt = grouped['Driving Time'].sum()

# dt
# Package number
# 1   0 days 00:15:00
# 2   0 days 00:25:00
# 3   0 days 01:00:00
# Name: Driving Time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: Ahh! So I should have used to_timedelta instead of to_datetime ?

Comment: @Rumble999: jep, just think about it, what is the sum of two dates? While the subtraction would make sense (results in duration/timedelta), the addition does not. What you have in your data is durations, not time, so to_timedelta is your way to go.